# cf push to IBM Cloud failed : Unable to install node: improper constraint: >=4.1.0 <5.5.0

Tags: ibm-cloud

I pushed an app to the IBM Cloud after a minor change (just some data, no code or dependencies).

```
cat: /VERSION: No such file or directory
-----> IBM SDK for Node.js Buildpack v4.0.1-20190930-1425
       Based on Cloud Foundry Node.js Buildpack 1.6.53

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json): >=4.1.0 <5.5.0
       engines.npm (package.json): unspecified (use default)
       **WARNING** Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node. See: http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html
       **ERROR** Unable to install node: improper constraint: >=4.1.0 <5.5.0
Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run all supply scripts: exit status 14
Exit status 223
Cell 155a85d3-8d60-425c-8e39-3a1183bfec2a stopping instance 5aad9d60-87d7-4153-b1ac-c3847c9a7a83
Cell 155a85d3-8d60-425c-8e39-3a1183bfec2a destroying container for instance 5aad9d60-87d7-4153-b1ac-c3847c9a7a83
Cell 155a85d3-8d60-425c-8e39-3a1183bfec2a successfully destroyed container for instance 5aad9d60-87d7-4153-b1ac-c3847c9a7a83

FAILED
Error restarting application: BuildpackCompileFailed
```

An older version of the app is running on the IBM Cloud already (from May 2019, I think).
So I wonder what changed so it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In IBM Cloud Foundry, the Node.js version must be specified like this

```
"engines": {
    "node": "12.x"
}
```

or

```
"engines": {
    "node": "12.10.x"
}
```

Comment: If you are using IBM Cloud Foundry now there is a warning: `WARNING node 12.x.x will no longer be available in new buildpacks released after 2022-04-01.`. I used `"node": "14.x"` and `"npm": "6.14.15"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try removing this completely on your package.json file.

```
"engines": {
    "node": "6.15.1",
    "npm": "3.10.10"
  },
```

Here's a quick [reference](https://github.com/SAP-samples/cloud-sample-node-chat/issues/3).